http HEAD request returns the prototype
My HTTP GET request works perfectly, returning body data and response headers. The exact same request with the extra paramter , { method: "HEAD" } as per the docs and response.header to console but it only returns the prototype of the headers not the response header. Server side I can see there was a sucessful HEAD request that was returned with a status 200.
async function getHead() {
    const url = document.getElementById('url').value;
    if(url.slice(0, 4) != 'http') {
        alert("URL must start with http or https!")
        document.getElementById("responseCode").innerHTML = "ERROR"
        document.getElementById("responseBody").innerHTML = ""
    };
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, { method: "HEAD" });
        if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Response status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    console.log(response.headers.entries());
    document.getElementById("responseCode").innerHTML = response.status;
    document.getElementById("responseBody").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        document.getElementById("responseBody").innerHTML = error.message;
    }
}

I'm expecting a response exactly the same as the GET fetch but without the body, but I'm just getting the prototype & constructor? Picture of the console:

Full HTML & JS here

What exactly do you mean, "the prototype"? What exactly are you seeing? What headers are being returned (as seen in the network inspector) that you expect to see?

Your response.headers works as a map of key/value pairs. You can get those pairs by using response.headers.entries(). It should work just fine if you work with it.

response.headers is an Object, no seed to await, and it's likely the object is NOT able to be stringify's since it is has methods, and complex properties that are NOT able to be stringified to JSON string

@user2804429 that gives me the prototype and the constructor?

@deceze I have added a picture of the console

Now your code is completely broken - scope is broken, variables missing, you've broken your code worse than it was

response.headers.entries() returns the iterator of the headers key/value pairs. The instance of both response.headers and response.headers.entries() would look like empty objects, but they should work fine if the server is sending the headers.

"Full HTML & JS here"
please update to put the relevant portions IN the question not some link many will never visit.

response.json() retuns the response body parsed as a JSON. Since a HEAD request doesn't return a body, it's not surprising that this parsing fails. This is the same error you'd get from trying to parse an empty string (e.g., JSON.parse('')).

when I use response.headers I just get the headers prototype not the head content of the fetch?

@BenJones what do you mean by "head content"? There's no response body for a HEAD request (or at least, shouldn't be)

from MDN Web Docs "The HEAD HTTP method requests the metadata of a resource in the form of headers that the server would have sent if the GET method was used instead." am I reading this wrong? @Mureinik manly I want the response code

manly I want the response code that's what response.status in YOUR code is - not sure why you are even trying to do with "JSON"

@jaromanda thank you, it was just console.log(response) !

The snippet below shows how to properly get your headers.
See Headers documentation for more details.


const MyURL = ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/');
const MyFetch = fetch(MyURL, {method: 'HEAD'});

MyFetch.then
(
  Response =>
  {
    const MyHeaders = Response.headers;
    
    for ( const HeaderPair of MyHeaders )
    {
      const [ Header, Value ] = HeaderPair;
      
      console.log(`${Header} = ${Value}`);
    }
  },
  Issue =>
  {
    console.log(Issue.message);
  }
);



IMPORTANT: Many thanks to Ray Wallace for providing a working link for fetching the headers. ;)
